# NPC resets when stepping on slope

Tags: godot, godot-3, gravity

This fella teleports back to spawn position every time it steps on a slope:

[image]

Artificial _physics_process called pc() and is being called by a timer every time the timer ticks, for this specific mob once every 0.05 as seen in the FPS variable. The problem is gravity.... I tried removing everything piece by piece to see what causes the problem, and it is gravity.

The problem it causes now is that when the npc steps on any slope, it is reset to spawn position.

```
extends KinematicBody

onready var bullet = preload("res://bullet.tscn")
var floatingtext = preload("res://UI/floatingtext.tscn")
onready var animation = $Spearskeleton/AnimationPlayer
onready var eyes = $Eyes
onready var ray = $RayCast
onready var hitbox = $Hitbox
#timers for movement
var directionChangeTimer = 0.0
var directionChangeInterval = 0.0
const minChangeInterval = 3.0
const maxChangeInterval = 12.0
#timers for combat 
var switchTimer = Timer.new()
var switchTimeMin = 1.0
var switchTimeMax = 1.5
#movement
const turn = 32
var vertical_velocity = Vector3()
var gravity = 30
var state = "walk"
var target
# stats
var health = 100
var maxhealth = 100
var damage = 2
var criticalChance = 0.70
var criticalMultiplier = 2.5
var criticalDefenseChance = 0.60
var criticalDefenseMultiplier = 2
var impact 
var blockdamage = 3
# artificial fps timer
onready var fps = $Timer
var FPS = 0.05
#bools
var blocking : bool
var kick : bool
var stabbing : bool
var slashing : bool
var slash_still : bool
var trust: bool
var is_blocking : bool
#live or die
var dead = false
# movement speed variables
var walkSpeed = 6.0
var chaseSpeed = 8 
var fleeSpeed = 12.50

# states list
enum {
    idle,
    chase,
    walk,
    attack,
    attack2,
    attack3,
    stunned,
    hit,
    block,
    dodge,
}

func _ready():
    walkSpeed = walkSpeed * (FPS * 10)
    chaseSpeed = chaseSpeed * (FPS *10)
    fleeSpeed = fleeSpeed * (FPS * 10)
    state = "walk"
    directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
    fps = Timer.new()
    add_child(fps)
    fps.wait_time = FPS
    fps.connect("timeout", self, "_on_Timer_timeout")
    fps.start()
    
    switchTimer.wait_time = rand_range(switchTimeMin, switchTimeMax)
    add_child(switchTimer)
    switchTimer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_SwitchTimer_timeout")
    switchTimer.start()


    
func _on_Timer_timeout():
    if not dead:
        chase(fps.wait_time)  # Pass the timer wait time instead of delta time
        pc(fps.wait_time)  # Pass the timer wait time instead of delta time
    if dead: 
        animation.play("dead")   
    
func _on_SwitchTimer_timeout():
    var randomValue = randf()
    var randblock = randf()

    if randomValue < 0.5:  # walks and stabs
        stabbing = true
        slashing = false
        kick = false
        slash_still = false
        trust = false
        impact = chaseSpeed 
    elif randomValue < 0.4:  # walks and slashes
        stabbing = false
        slashing = true
        kick = false
        slash_still = false
        trust = false
        impact = chaseSpeed
    elif randomValue < 0.6:  # kicks
        stabbing = false
        slashing = false
        kick = true
        slash_still = false
        trust = false
        impact = 45 + rand_range(15,30)
    elif randomValue < 0.8:  # stays still and slashes
        stabbing = false
        slashing = true
        kick = false
        slash_still = true
        trust = false
        impact = chaseSpeed
    else:
        stabbing = false
        slashing = false
        kick = false
        slash_still = false
        trust = true
        impact = chaseSpeed 
        
    if randblock < 0.5:
        is_blocking = true
    else:
        is_blocking = false 
        
        

    switchTimer.wait_time = rand_range(switchTimeMin, switchTimeMax)
    switchTimer.start()


func onhit(damage):
    if not blocking: 
        if damage <= 0:
            return
    # Apply critical defense chance
        if randf() <= criticalDefenseChance:
            damage = damage / criticalDefenseMultiplier
            state = stunned
        # Basic formula for damage
        health -= damage
        var text = floatingtext.instance()
        text.amount = float(damage)
        add_child(text)
        if health <= 0:
            dead = true
        if health <= -200:
            self.queue_free()
    if blocking: 
        if damage <= 0:
            return
    # Apply critical defense chance
        if randf() <= criticalDefenseChance:
            damage = damage / criticalDefenseMultiplier
        # Basic formula for damage
        health -= damage / blockdamage
        var text = floatingtext.instance()
        text.amount = float(damage)
        add_child(text)
    if health <= 0:
            dead = true 
    if health <= -200:
            self.queue_free()

func attack():
        var enemies = hitbox.get_overlapping_bodies()
        for enemy in enemies:
            if enemy.is_in_group("Player"):
                if randf() <= criticalChance:
                    var criticalDamage = damage * criticalMultiplier
                    enemy.onhitP(criticalDamage)
                else:
                    enemy.onhitP(damage)


func knockback(): 
    var enemies = hitbox.get_overlapping_bodies()
    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.is_in_group("Player"):
            enemy.onhitKnockback(impact)



func chase(delta):
#locate players and define distances and orientation
    var players = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Player")
    var target = null

    if players.size() > 0:
        target = players[0]
        var minDistance = self.global_transform.origin.distance_to(target.global_transform.origin)

        for player in players:
            var distance = self.global_transform.origin.distance_to(player.global_transform.origin)
            if distance < minDistance:
                minDistance = distance
                target = player
#state logic based on range 
    if target != null:
        var distanceToPlayer = self.global_transform.origin.distance_to(target.global_transform.origin)

        if distanceToPlayer > 0 and distanceToPlayer <= 20:
            state = chase
            target = target
            if distanceToPlayer > 0 and distanceToPlayer <= 2.5 and health >= maxhealth/3.5:
                state = attack
                target = target     
            elif distanceToPlayer > 0 and distanceToPlayer <= 2 and health <= maxhealth/3.5:
                state = block
                target = target
        else:
                state = walk
    else:
        state = walk

    match state:
        idle:
            blocking = false
            animation.play("idle", 0.1)
        attack:
            blocking = false
            if target != null:
                eyes.look_at(target.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
                rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
                if  stabbing: 
                    animation.play("stab", 0.2)
                    move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity(chaseSpeed)) 
                    knockback()

    
                elif slashing:
                    animation.play("slash walking", 0.25)
                    move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity(chaseSpeed)) 
                    knockback()


                elif slash_still:
                    animation.play("slash", 0.25)   
                    knockback()


                elif trust: 
                    animation.play("forceful trust", 0.25)
                    knockback()


                elif kick: 
                    animation.play("kick", 0.15)
                    move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity(chaseSpeed))    
                    
        walk:
            blocking = false
            animation.play("walk", 0.2)
            directionChangeTimer += delta
            if directionChangeTimer >= directionChangeInterval:
                directionChangeTimer = 0.0
                directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
                changeRandomDirection()
            move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity(walkSpeed))  # Pass the walk speed
        chase:
            blocking = false
            animation.play("chase", 0, 1.5)
            if target != null:
                var targetDirection = (target.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin).normalized()
                eyes.look_at(global_transform.origin + targetDirection, Vector3.UP)
                rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
                move_and_slide(targetDirection * getSlideVelocity(chaseSpeed).length())  # Pass the chase speed
        block:
            if is_blocking:
                if target != null:
                    var fleeDirection = (global_transform.origin - target.global_transform.origin).normalized()
                    eyes.look_at(global_transform.origin - fleeDirection, Vector3.UP)
                    rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
                    blocking = true
                    animation.play("block") 
            else:
                if target != null:
                    eyes.look_at(target.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
                    rotate_y(deg2rad(eyes.rotation.y * turn))
                    animation.play("stab", 0.2)
                    move_and_slide(getSlideVelocity(chaseSpeed)) 
                    damage += 6
                    knockback()
                        


func changeRandomDirection():
    var randomDirection = Vector3(rand_range(-1, 1), 0, rand_range(-1, 1)).normalized()
    var lookRotation = randomDirection.angle_to(Vector3.FORWARD)
    rotate_y(lookRotation)

func getSlideVelocity(speed: float) -> Vector3:
    var forwardVector = -transform.basis.z
    return forwardVector * speed



func pc(delta):
    var players = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Player")
    if players.size() > 0:
        var player = players[0]
        var distanceToPlayer = self.global_transform.origin.distance_to(player.global_transform.origin)
        if distanceToPlayer > 30:
            self.visible = false
            directionChangeTimer = 0.0
            directionChangeInterval = rand_range(minChangeInterval, maxChangeInterval)
        else:
            self.visible = true
    else:
        self.visible = true


    if not is_on_floor():
        vertical_velocity += Vector3.DOWN * gravity * 2 * delta
    else:
        vertical_velocity = -get_floor_normal() * gravity / 2.5

    move_and_slide(vertical_velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

Comment: fixed it by using move_and_collide instead of move_and_slide

Comment: If that's the answer you would accept to your question, then it should be posted as an answer rather than a comment.